# Playing a sine wave of varying pitch

Tags: java, javasound, trigonometry

I have a (pretty simple) piece of code I've thrown together which plays a sine wave of a specific frequency and plays it - it works no problem:

```
public class Sine {

    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 16 * 1024;
    private static final int FREQ = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {
        final AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(SAMPLE_RATE, 8, 1, true, true);
        try(SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af)) {
            line.open(af, SAMPLE_RATE);
            line.start();
            play(line);
            line.drain();
        }
    }

    private static void play(SourceDataLine line) {
        byte[] arr = getData();
        line.write(arr, 0, arr.length);
    }

    private static byte[] getData() {
        final int LENGTH = SAMPLE_RATE * 100;
        final byte[] arr = new byte[LENGTH];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            double angle = (2.0 * Math.PI * i) / (SAMPLE_RATE/FREQ);
            arr[i] = (byte) (Math.sin(angle) * 127);
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

I can also modify the `getData()` method to return a byte array that produces a gradual change in pitch as it plays, no problems there.

However, I'm struggling with a way to continuously play a sine wave which I can smoothly update the frequency and amplitude of "live" - i.e. having `FREQ` in the above example changed by another thread and have the sound update in real time. I've tried creating the byte array and then filling it later in a separate thread based on the required values, but either seem to get nothing or distortion. I've also tried writing to the `SourceDataLine` in chunks, but this provides "blocks" of discrete frequencies rather than the smooth transition I'm after. A search around doesn't seem to provide much other than what I've already tried.

It's for an emulation of a theramin, so ideally needs to be as smooth low-latency as possible.

I can do it ahead of time no problem - but live is proving tricky. Has anyone any ideas or examples they could share?

Comment: You might have better luck with [javax.sound.midi](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/package-summary.html).  MIDI specs. Channel Pressure & Pitch Bend would seem to fit the use-case.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did think of that, but then I think I can only bend a tone or so either side of the note I'm currently playing, so would need to find some mechanism for "silently" (for want of a better word) switching between the notes I was playing as the pitch varied, then use pitch bend to manage the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a Java theremin, and it can be played at this url:

http://www.hexara.com/VSL/JTheremin.htm

On that site, there are two links to the Java Gaming forum where there was some discussion on the various issues involved.

I use a wavetable, rather than a sin function, to generate the PCM data, but the method of changing the variable that is fed into the sin function can be set up in a similar manner.

The easiest thing to do is to have a volatile float or double in the base class that is consulted in the innermost while loop where the sound bytes are being created. Your GUI can update this variable, and the while loop can base the pitch calculation on this.

Consulting the pitch variable once per buffer load will not be satisfactory, so the next logical step is to have your while loop check this variable with every frame you process! Yes, that means referring to the pitch variable 44100 times per second, if that is your frame rate.

But even so, the problem remains that response is limited by the manner in which the JVM time slices threads. When the sound thread is not actively looping, it is also not reading the new values that have been placed into the "pitch" variable! Recall that while the sound thread is quite able to keep the frame rate constant, it is not doing so in "real time," but in bursts of activity. Thus the GUI may overwrite the pitch value several times during the period when the sound processing thread is sleeping, resulting in pitch discontinuities.

To get around this, I made a FIFO where I store and timestamp all the GUI-generated pitch changing events. In the innermost sound processing loop, this FIFO is consulted (instead of the volatile double mentioned earlier) to determine the pitch value to be used, on a per-sample basis. Since the pitch values from a GUI will be discrete values and come at varying times, you need a method of interpolating pitch values to fill the gaps. I use the time stamps and values to calculate a per-frame interpolation, and thus update a pitch variable in the innermost loop every sample.

I think there are a lot of issues, still, with the solution I wrote, and am looking forward to revisiting this!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that! I'll have a look at your approach and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I made the PCM-producing part of the Theremin implement a TargetDataLine, if that helps. Also, I'm not sure if I was clear, I meant to say that the method of updating the pitch calculation could be the same, regardless of whether a pitch table or direct sine function is used. Good luck with the project! I'd love to hear more about how it works out for you. I plan to get back to it before too long, myself, as well as an FM synthesizer project that is partially done. (Involves yet more sine waves having their frequencies altered.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are only reading from the data array once, so regardless of whether the data is modified, only one pitch will be produced. I would think you would need to be playing a shorter wave inside a loop that rereads the data array each iteration. I don't know how the SourceDataLine class functions though, so I don't know if this would produce the sound unsegmented.

Comment: I know the above code just produces one pitch - that's the easy part ;) I'm just not sure of the best way to modify it to produce a "live" updatable variable pitch. And yes, writing to it in chunks in a loop produces a segmented sound rather than the continuous transform that I'm after.

Comment: Do you have the source code for SourceDataLine? It seems like you'd need to know exactly how and when it is reading the array you pass it.

Comment: It's a standard Java class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html

Comment: So right here in the `SourceDataLine.write` documentation it says: "Writes audio data to the mixer via this source data line. The requested number of bytes of data are read from the specified array, starting at the given offset into the array, and written to the data line's buffer." So the array is written to the data line's buffer, which is not visible. I doubt there is any way to access the buffer as it is being played.

Comment: I agree you can't really rely on sticking bytes in the buffer and hoping for the best - too many unknowns. But given that, I'm not sure of the best way of achieving what I'm trying to do!

Comment: Have you read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/chapter4.html ? It seems like there is some useful information there about realtime and interactive audio playback. It says that you can specify a small buffer size so that you don't have latency when your data array changes.

Comment: @berry120 the key to variable pitch requires a more sophisticated [numerically controlled oscilator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerically_controlled_oscillator). You need to keep track of the phase and [adjust it accordingly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/dsp/ref/nco.html) to facilitate shifts in pitch.